# Is it possible to access metadata/layers in mbtiles via mapbox gl?

Tags: mapbox-gl

In a mapbox-gl map, given the source:

```
map.addSource('myTileSource', {
    type: "vector",
    tiles: "url to source tiles.pbf",
});
```

is it possible to get all the layers and/or metadata for the tiles inside that source? This is possible in node with node-mbtiles, but wondering if it is possible directly in mapbox-gl via javascript? Something like `map.getLayersFromSource` would be awesome.

Comment: Also posted on GIS stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of an official API method to get the information you're looking for. However, exploring Mapbox Studio reveals that there is an HTTP endpoint that returns the desired information:

`https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7.json?access_token=[Mapbox Token here]`

This returns a description of the source, including a list of layers.

```
{
    "attribution": "...",
    "vector_layers": [
        {
            "id": "layer id",
            "fields": {
                "field_1": "description for field 1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is obviously specific to Mapbox sources and won't work for vector tiles from different sources.

Comment: Right. Looks like I'll have to do this server-side. I'm using the mbtiles-server FYI.

Comment: It's not Mapbox specific: that's [TileJSON](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec).